# Wordpress Posts

Tags: wordpress

I have about 10 different category posts etc.

As you know, withing each category there is the next and previous navigation to toggle between posts. When you reach the Last post in a category, the next navigation then takes you to the NEXT category...

My question is, is there there a way to loop only withing the category with the next and previous?

Comment: There is actually a Wordpress dedicated SE: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, when you are implementing the Next and Previous posts, you would use this code:

```
 <?php next_post_link('format', 'link', 'in_same_cat', 'excluded_categories'); ?>
```

So for example:

```
 <?php next_post_link('', '', TRUE, ''); ?>
```